# using python to auto login to a website form a txt, and then removing the first line of the txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For short how do i make python take the first line of a txt which is email:pass and login to the website, then remove the first line and then auto log out,

So im trying to make a tool, where it will take a txt file and use the first line and login to a website so here is the code i have so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://minecraft.net/")

#open tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 
# You can use (Keys.CONTROL + 't') on other OSs

# Load a page 
driver.get('https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/login')
# Make the tests...

# Login via details
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('emailField').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w') 


sleep(2)
```

and i just need help figuring out how to make python take the first line of a txt file, and enter it for email, pass. (yes i know how to do everything for xpath, so no need to help me with clicking the login button)

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can open a text file like this and read first line into `first_line`:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    first_line = f.readline().strip()
```

Where `myfile.txr` is your text file and you can use it amywhere.